# Download JSON file and print it using PHP

Tags: php, json, amazon-s3

I have a couple JSON files in my Amazon S3 bucket which were made public. So I was trying to display the contents of the JSO file using PHP. I used:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

but the above code gave me a JSON parse error. Can someone please help me how to read this JSON file from my S3 and display it on my front-end?

Comment: whats your ``file_get_contents``output like?

Comment: It was giving me the json Parse error.

Comment: when you ``var_dump(file_get_contents($url))`` are you getting your expected content?

Comment: It is printing the entire JSON file from S3

Comment: if you are getting json Parse error then something is wrong with the json format. you can try with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: `json_decode` only works with "UTF-8 encoded strings" so if your JSON string is not UTF-8 encoded then change encoding to UTF-8 first before calling this method.